# Is it necessary to call Shutdown and Close after every socket operation?

Tags: c#, sockets

The code in question is pretty close to the examples

here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx (server)

and

here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx (client)

Close and Shutdown are used in both of these examples. The reason I'm wondering is I have played around with using Close/Shutdown and where to place them, and so far haven't really been seeing much benefit in using them at all.

Let's say my client sends a message every 2 seconds, should I used Close/Shutdown in this case? What about a message every 2 minutes?

As far as I can tell, if I completely remove all calls to Close and Shutdown from the server and the client side, this has no effect on the code continuing to run on either side.

Is there an explicit reason I should or should not be using these in every case?

Comment: I think the remarks section of the MSDN on `Close()` answers your question: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This depends on what kind of communication you need to have between your client and server. Http is a stateless communications protocol for example, which means no state is stored on the connection, you disconnect and reconnect. But even the http protocol defines Connection: Keep-Alive header to keep the connection open to allow multiple resource requests to use the same connection, because opening a connection is an overhead

Comment: So if you have a chat application or an application that transmits real time data, you might not want to close the connection and reopen it. Keeping the connection open will allow transmission to be available in both directions. it is almost always the case that, clients connect to the server and not the opposite therefore, if you disconnect, the server cannot send anything to the client unless the client reconnects

Comment: When your application reaches tens of thousands of users though, you need to scale your hardware to allow connections more than the limited port range of your operating system reserves for assigning to the incoming tcp connections. This requires more of a network expertise (load balancers etc) then software and if you have that kind of load, you will anyways have the resources to afford it :)

Comment: And not to mention the authentication overhead. One of the reasons the http protocol has that Keep-Alive option is to allow requests on an already authenticated connection instead of re-authenticating the client which means, as in NTLM for example, two more round trips between the client and the server

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to close, shutdown, or dispose a socket until you're finished with it. You can continue to read data as you please until you're completely done communicating. If the socket is idle for a long period of time, on the order of 15+ minutes, it may be automatically closed by the OS or some other system. Otherwise, just leave it open until you're done using it.